# Need to unplug computer to power it since I installed ubuntu 16 (dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, power-management, hibernate

I have a PC with both OS installed (Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 10) on an SSD (Samsung, 500Gb)

Since the moment I installed Ubuntu and my PC boots with GRUB, every time I want to turn it back on I have to unplug the power cord for 30s or else it wont start.

Also, when I'm on Windows and the PC hibernates I can't turn it back on, I have to unplug, wait, and turn it on (And the power led keeps twinkling for a while after unpluging the cord).

The computer is brand new, and its unlikely this being due to a hardware issue.

Let me know if there is more relevant info I can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: I think these are the effect of so-called hybrid sleep or hibernate. I'm experiencing same thing there.

Comment: `zless /var/log/pm*` will show Power Management logs.

Comment: Sorry to hear it, but glad I'm not the only one with this issue, @waltinator I'm on an ubuntu 16 pc now, but not the one with the issue, I'll make sure to check that ASAP

Answer (score 3):

With the Samsung SSD, you'll want to check that it has the latest firmware. Learn how to do this by looking at http://www.storagereview.com/how_to_upgrade_samsung_ssd_firmware.

With Windows, you'll want to turn off hibernation. In an elevated command prompt terminal, type `powercfg -h off`.

With Windows, you'll also need to turn off `fast boot`. You'll find the setting in the power control panel.

Cheers, Al